# Specific array size declaration. Java

Tags: java

Recently I have found an array declaration in Java, as for me it was some kind specific.

`String[] book = new String[9_999_999 + 1];`

Could someone please clarify how to read this declaration correctly.

Comment: What is confusing? The underscores?

Comment: can be simplified to `new String[10000000]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) says:

> **3.10.1. Integer Literals**
>
> Underscores are allowed as separators between digits that denote the integer.

[Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) says:

> **Primitive Data types**
>
> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature enables you, for example. to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.
>
> For instance, if your code contains numbers with many digits, you can use an underscore character to separate digits in groups of three, similar to how you would use a punctuation mark like a comma, or a space, as a separator.
>
> The following example shows other ways you can use the underscore in numeric literals:
>
> ```
> long creditCardNumber = 1234_5678_9012_3456L;
> long socialSecurityNumber = 999_99_9999L;
> float pi =  3.14_15F;
> long hexBytes = 0xFF_EC_DE_5E;
> long hexWords = 0xCAFE_BABE;
> long maxLong = 0x7fff_ffff_ffff_ffffL;
> byte nybbles = 0b0010_0101;
> long bytes = 0b11010010_01101001_10010100_10010010;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore characters are used to separate the groups of digits. It is used to add readability to the code. So , 9_999_99 is nothing but 9999999. The total will be 10000000 sized array(9999999 + 1).